# Explain Node's st module fd and stat configuration

Tags: node.js, configuration, static

Node's st module [documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/st) mentions `fd` and `stat` configuration:

```
cache: { // specify cache:false to turn off caching entirely

    fd: {
      max: 1000, // number of fd's to hang on to
      maxAge: 1000*60*60, // amount of ms before fd's expire
    },

    stat: {
      max: 5000, // number of stat objects to hang on to
      maxAge: 1000 * 60, // number of ms that stats are good for
    },

    ...

}
```

But what are these and how do they impact's `st`'s delivery of static files? Can you give examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are configurations, for `st` cache module which is [`lru-cache`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/lru-cache).

- `fd`

Which stands for [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). Everytime `sd` module want to serve a file and needs to read the content from it, it needs to have/open a file descriptor. Caching file descriptor will remove the time taken to open a file.

If the file is moved or deleted, reading with the file descriptor will still result in the old content.

Each system has a maximum amount of open file descriptors per process and globally, and once you run out, you can't open anymore files. So make sure you set the `cache.fd.max` option lesser than amount per process.

- `stat`

It represents the [result of calls to fs.stat and friends](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_class_fs_stats). It is needed for setting etag, or responding with a 304.

The `max` option, is the maximum number of items/size and the `maxAge`, is the max amount of time an item can remain in memory.

Obviously, the for all the cache types(fd, stat, content,...) the higher the numbers(max and maxAge) are, some requests are served way faster, but more memory is consumed.

Setting `fd.max` to a optimized amount might be tricky. Since for each connection to be served a file descriptor is opened so technically. You would want to leave some space for the connections you want to handle, because if you hit the limit, your server won't receive anymore connections. Set it according to number of concurrent connections your server is expected to handle and max number of open files for your process in your system. Here's how you would check/change the max number in linux: http://cherry.world.edoors.com/CPZKoGkpxfbQ

As for `stat.max`, I suggest setting it according to available memory. I suggest testing/measuring it in your production system to find how much memory is used per 1 stat object, so you can decide.

Setting `maxAge` depends on the frequency of your files being updated.

Comment: I know very little about caching, and would really like to find more information about this module, and how to use it's caching options. What resources can you recommend to help me get the best out of it? Trying hard to avoid asking another SO question here.